# Obtaining fitted values for lmer mixed-effects models at an aggregated level

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Say I have a data set `df` of individual patients, the doctor they saw, the cost of each visit, and the patient age and sex. I want to use a mixed-effects model with a random effect term for each patient and each doctor and a fixed-effect for the age and sex. Many patients have repeated measures where they saw different doctors so the data set has a partially crossed design.
So in lmer, I have the formula:
`m1 <- lmer(cost ~ age + sex + (1|patient) + (1|doctor), data=df)`

Then when I call
`fitted(m1)`
It seems that I get the fitted values (cost) for each observation in the data set.

How do I get the fitted values aggregated at the DOCTOR level? I want to know the predicted cost for each doctor, with a confidence interval. I think that it is possible to do this manually (I am not sure exactly how)  but I want to  know if there is  a built in method to do this.

Thank you

Comment: If you are interested in the predictions for each doctor, why do you treat doctors as random effects?

Comment: Can you explain how that is a contradiction? thanks

Comment: [What is the difference between fixed effect, random effect and mixed effect models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode)